# Is there a way to view Coinbase Pro transactions for sub portfolios via their API?

Tags: coinbase-api

For some unknown reason I can only fetch Coinbase Pro transactions (withdrawals and deposits) for my Default Portfolio. This behavior doesn't seem to work with my sub portfolios. What's perhaps worse, I can't find any way to see transfers between portfolios!

Can someone else please confirm if they can see transactions between two portfolios using the pro.coinbase.com transactions api?

Answer (score 0):

I've come to realize that the issue is with CCXT-JS. That tools does not seem to expose `https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts/{account_id}/ledger` at the time of writing.

Comment: This issue has been corrected within CCXT.